Serialize Object using JsonConvert with specific format
I am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject method to serialize this object:
var objx = new JsonObject
{
    ["prob1"] = new JsonObject
    {
        ["phone"] = "1019577756",
        ["name"] = "Jan",
        ["type"] = "Agent"
    }
};

I am using this code:
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objx, Formatting.None,
      new JsonSerializerSettings()
      {
          ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
      });

But I get this result:
{
    "prob1":
    {
         "phone":
         {
               "_value": "1019577756",
               "Value": "1019577756",
               "Options": null
         },
         "name": 
         {
               "_value": "Jan",
               "Value": "Jan",
               "Options": null
         },
         "type"
         {
               "_value": "Agent",
               "Value": "Agent",
               "Options": null
         }
   }
}

But I need like this:
{
   "prob1": 
   {
       "phone": "1019577756",
       "name": "Jan",
       "type": "Agent"
   }
}

Can I use JsonSerializerSettings, but I do not know what exactly I need to do

You seem to be mixing NewtonSoft.Json and System.Text.Json. If that's true: don't. Pick one and try again.

Instead of using JsonObject, why don't you use a Dictionary<string, ContactInfo>? Where the ContactInfo class holds the properties like phone, name, type

You are mixing the JSON serialization library. JsonObject is from the System.Text.Json library while you are serializing with Netwonsoft.Json.
Either fully implement in System.Text.Json:
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objx, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions 
    { 
        WriteIndented = false, 
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles 
    });

Reference: Migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json
Or fully implement in Newtonsoft.Json:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var objx = new JObject
{
    ["prob1"] = new JObject
    {
        ["phone"] = "1019577756",
        ["name"] = "Jan",
        ["type"] = "Agent"
    }
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objx, Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    });


Demo @ .NET Fiddle

This happens to me as well from time to time. Many of the classes and methods of these two libraries are so similar. It's easy to mix them up.
